# Minecraft command block player not found error

Tags: command, minecraft, minecraft-commands

I want to give new players items if they join my server, so i used a scoreboard with value 0 if they are new and 1 if they have been on my server before. I used an always active unconditional repeat command block with the command `/execute as @a if score @s first_time matches 0`. I checked that this one works fine. I placed a conditional always active chain command block in that one with the command `give @s stone 1`, and the output is "No player found". Why?

Answer (score 3):

The selector `@s` refers to self, meaning the command block is running `/give` on itself, which it cannot do since it's not a player.

Additionally, for your scenario, this is one thing you could do (unconditional repeating command block followed by conditional chain command block, both always active):

```
give @a[tag=!first_time] <item>
tag @a add first_time
```

You can also use a datapack function to do this cleaner and all in one tick (and you can use @s).
Datapack Function (`firsttimeitem.mcfunction`):

```
give @s <item>
tag @s add first_time
```

Repeating Command Block (or `tick.mcfunction` in datapack, your preference):

```
execute as @a[tag=!first_time] run function <yourdatapacknamespace>:firsttimeitem
```

*Note: You need to replace anything in triangle brackets.*

Comment: and what if there are more items

Comment: If there are more items you can add more `/give` commands to the function/command block chain. And if you need to do anything else you can run those respective commands.